# How to set Gradle wrapper version when create new project for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I create new Gradle project with IntelliJ IDEA, the Gradle wrapper version is always 4.10.2, but I have updated my Gradle to 5.2.1.

This is the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I tried update Gradle wrapper version with:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 5.2.1
```

It works.

But, I want to set the Gradle wrapper version when I create new project, not after it.

How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently IDEA uses the version of gradle that comes bundled with the IDE's gradle plugin.

Your request has been filed in IntelliJ's issue tracker before.
You can see and vote for it here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177325

Comment: Agree, its a good feature to have, but still there is no update on this ticket.